# How to store UserState and ConversationState in Azure Cosmos DB (BotFramework)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, azure-cosmosdb, state-management

I'm doing a bot with de Microsoft Bot Framework version V4. The documentation is really awful, and I'm having problems with Cosmos DB (Azure) when I try to store de UserSate and the ConversationState.

I tried every result in Google but nothing has worked yet. Plus, there no much information about the framework really.

Bellow is the code of the file Startup.cs.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddBot<SeguritoBot>(options =>
   {
       var secretKey = Configuration.GetSection("botFileSecret")?.Value;
       var botFilePath = Configuration.GetSection("botFilePath")?.Value;

    // Loads .bot configuration file and adds a singleton that your Bot can access through dependency injection.
    var botConfig = BotConfiguration.Load(botFilePath ?? @".\Segurito.bot", secretKey);
   services.AddSingleton(sp => botConfig ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"The .bot config file could not be loaded. ({botConfig})"));

    // Retrieve current endpoint.
    var environment = _isProduction ? "production" : "development";
   var service = botConfig.Services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Type == "endpoint" && s.Name == environment);
   if (!(service is EndpointService endpointService))
   {
       throw new InvalidOperationException($"The .bot file does not contain an endpoint with name '{environment}'.");
   }

   options.CredentialProvider = new SimpleCredentialProvider(endpointService.AppId, endpointService.AppPassword);

    // Creates a logger for the application to use.
    ILogger logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SeguritoBot>();

    // Catches any errors that occur during a conversation turn and logs them.
    options.OnTurnError = async (context, exception) =>
   {
       logger.LogError($"Exception caught : {exception}");
       await context.SendActivityAsync("Sorry, it looks like something went wrong.");
   };

   var optionsConversation = new CosmosDbStorageOptions()
   {
       CosmosDBEndpoint = new Uri("--secret--"),
       AuthKey = "--secret--",
       DatabaseId = "--secret--",
       CollectionId = "--secret--"
   };

   var optionsUser = new CosmosDbStorageOptions()
   {
       CosmosDBEndpoint = new Uri("--secret--"),
       AuthKey = "--secret--",
       DatabaseId = "--secret--",
       CollectionId = "--secret--"
   };

   IStorage dataStoreConversationState = new CosmosDbStorage(optionsConversation);
   IStorage dataStoreUserState = new CosmosDbStorage(optionsUser);

   options.Middleware.Add(new ConversationState<ConversationState>(dataStoreConversationState));
   options.Middleware.Add(new UserState<UserState>(dataStoreUserState));
   });
}
```

The last to lines are giving the error:

```
The non-generic type 'ConversationState' cannot be used with type arguments
The non-generic type 'ConversationState' cannot be used with type arguments
```

Comment: @TomasPicierri Did the answer below help you? Do you need any more info? If it helped please make sure to upvote and/or mark it as the answer to help other people in the future.

Comment: Hi @DrewMarsh, my code is a mess right now, so I can't test yours right now. But the links did helped me to understand more the framework. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure where you got this code from, but it looks like it's from a pre-release build. `ConversationState` and `UserState` are no longer middleware and no longer generic (e.g. don't have type arguments).

This is what a `Startup::ConfigureServices` should look like when using CosmosDB for state storage on a 4.x release build:

```
public class Startup
{
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
        // Only need a single storage instance unless you really are storing your conversation state and user state in two completely DB instances
        var storage = new CosmosDbStorage(new CosmosDbStorageOptions
        {
            // … set options here …
        });

        var conversationState = new ConversationState(storage);
        var userState = new UserState(storage);

        // Add the states as singletons
        services.AddSingleton(conversationState);
        services.AddSingleton(userState);

        // Create state properties accessors and register them as singletons
        services.AddSingleton(conversationState.CreateProperty<YourBotConversationState>("MyBotConversationState"));
        services.AddSingleton(userState.CreateProperty<YourBotUserState>("MyBotUserState"));

        services.AddBot<SeguritoBot>(options =>
        {
           // … set options here …
        });
     }
}
```

Now, in your bot, if you want to access those properties, you take them as dependencies via the constructor:

```
public class SeguritoBot : IBot
{
    private readonly ConversationState _conversationState;
    private readonly UserState _userState;
    private readonly IStatePropertyAccessor<YourBotConversationState> _conversationStatePropertyAccessor;
    private readonly IStatePropertyAccessor<YourBotUserState> _userStatePropertyAccessor;

    public SeguritoBot(
        ConversationState conversationState, 
        UserState userState,
        IStatePropertyAccessor<YourBotConversationState> conversationStatePropertyAccessor,
        IStatePropertyAccessor<YourBotUserState> userStatePropertyAccesssor)
    {
        _conversationState = conversationState;
        _userState = userState;
        _conversationStatePropertyAcessor = conversationStatePropertyAcessor;
        _userStatePropertyAcessor = userStatePropertyAcessor;
    }

    public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var currentConversationState = await _conversationStatePropertyAccessor.GetAsync(
            turnContext,
            () => new YourBotConversationState(), 
            cancellationToken);

        // Access properties for this conversation
        // currentConversationState.SomeProperty

        // Update your conversation state property
        await _conversationStatePropertyAccessor.SetAsync(turnContext, currentConversationState, cancellationToken);

        // Commit any/all changes to conversation state properties
        await _conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Obviously you can do the same with the user state property and you can support multiple properties per state scope with more calls to `CreateProperty` and injecting those `IStatePropertyAccessor<T>` as well, etc.

Comment: Hi Drew! I'm really lost with these because the Microsoft's documentation is really bad and it's changing all the time. Your code helped me a lot to understand some concepts. Sadly other things broke when I made the changes. Do you have some link with info about the concepts of ConversationSate and UserSate so I can read upon?

Comment: You can look at these two articles for some help on concepts, etc.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: Let us know what broke and how.

Comment: Yes, @DanaV's links are the ones you want to check out and if you are still having a problem please post another question and we'll do our best to help you out. And, if you have a second and you this answer useful, please give it an upvote and/or mark as the answer so it can help other people in the future! 